# How to query CouchDB view by specific element in key array?

Tags: couchdb

I have the following view in CouchDB that is reduced via `_count`:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.type === "signature") {
    emit([doc.worksite_id, doc.uid, doc.timestamp], doc._id);
  }
}
```

There are cases where rather than using `group_level=2` in my query to get my count values sorted by `doc.worksite_id` and `doc.uid` pairs (as shown below)...

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "key": [
        "worksite-1",
        "id-1"
      ],
      "value": 2
    },
    {
      "key": [
        "worksite-2",
        "id-1"
      ],
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "key": [
        "worksite-2",
        "id-2"
      ],
      "value": 26
    }
  ]
}
```

...I, instead, need to get count values sorted strictly by `doc.uid`, with an example of something similar to the following:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "key": [
        "id-1"
      ],
      "value": 3
    },
    {
      "key": [
        "id-2"
      ],
      "value": 26
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there an efficient way to do this based on the current view I'm querying from? And if not, what is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: From my understanding, the way indexes are built, you can't  query by doc.uid with the same index. Indexes with multiple fields are indexed by levels: worksite_id > doc.uid. You can decide the deep level that you want to go but you can't decide the start level.

For your use case, you will need to create another view that starts with doc.uid

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thank you for the information!